# Angular - data not available inside ng-init

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Angular partial - HTML. 
BaseCtrl

```
 <div ng-controller="SelectTagCtrl">       
     <input type="text" ng-init="setTags(viewData['users'])" ui-select2="tagAllOptions" ng-model="tagsSelection" name="users"  />   
     {{viewData['users']}} ECHOES CORRECTLY. 
     But undefined when passed inside ng-init callback.
 </div>

 <input type="text" class="span12" placeholder="Brief Description" name="description" value="{{viewData['description']}}">
 ECHOES CORRECTLY.
```

Controller.js

```
function SelectTagCtrl(){
 $scope.setTags = function(data){       
    // data is undfined when viewData['users'] is used. <-- PROBLEM
    // correct when I pass some static string. 
 }     
}


//POPULATING viewData to be used inside view partial.  

function BaseCtrl(){
    $http.get(url).success(function(data){   
    $scope.viewData = data.data || [];        
    $scope.view_type = $scope.viewData['view_type'];
    $scope.fields = data.data.fields;                   
    console.log($scope);

  }).error();
}
```

Comment: It is most likely because the `$http.get` has not completed by the time the ng-init directive is compiled.

Comment: That depends what are you trying to do exactly in `setTags`? Off the  cusp I'd say move your logic inside of `setTags` into your success callback and don't use `ng-init` at all.

Comment: I tried that. as it seemed obvious. but that affects other things.

Comment: What is it that you would like to achieve? I don't think this is the intended use for `ng-init` it is meant to initialize values before the application is bootstrapped. I'm not sure it is possible to use it with asynchronous calls. It could be possible with perhaps some elaborate use of [$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q).

Comment: It would work thought not correctly. If I put the logic of setTags inside success callback. but problem there is if I update the ng-model value the old value is getting lost. I will update the question with my scenario

Comment: basically I am making a ajax version of this fiddle[http://jsfiddle.net/maxl/hWXBv/14/]. where `tagsSelection` would come in ajax call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `timeout` would be a workaround, instead I would take a `$scope` variable inside the controller to know if the ajax call has completed.

The problem is `ng-init` might get called before ajax completion.

I already had `ui-if` directive configured in my angular project, so I used it with the combination of `$scope` variable to get the things working.

```
<div ng-controller="SelectTagCtrl" ui-if="ajax_done">       
     <input type="text" ng-init="setTags(viewData['users'])" ui-select2="tagAllOptions" ng-model="tagsSelection" name="users"  />  
</div>
```

And inside controller,

```
 $http.get(gurl + '.json').success(function(data,status){
      // some stuff
      $scope.ajax_done = true;
 }).error();
```

Because of angular's magical [two-way binding](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04), the element will get updated. Now it sees that ajax request is completed, `ui-if` will get a truthy value and ng-init directive of the element will get a chance to execute its callback.

**EDIT**: `ui-if` was removed from [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/) in favour of [ng-if](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) which is now built in.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two different changes to [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxl/hWXBv/14/) that appear to work.

[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/hWXBv/18/) - this version uses `$scope.$apply(exp)` as described in the documentation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply) and is useful when you are modifying angular bound data outside of the angular framework. In this example `setTimeout` is the culprit.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("updateVal" );

    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.updateVal2();
    });
    console.log($scope.tagsSelection);
},5000);
```

[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/hWXBv/19/) - this version uses angular's wrapper for `setTimeout` called the [$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout#%24apply) service.

```
$timeout(function(){
    console.log("updateVal" );

    $scope.updateVal2();
    console.log($scope.tagsSelection);
},5000);
```

Comment: Found your answer useful. +1, but setTimeOut is not the correct way to solve this. I will post how I solved my specific problem

Comment: Yeah it definitely felt like I wasn't necessarily answering the question per se but glad it helped!